# Delete first rows after qualified ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's suppose that I have the following table called **Orders**:

```
---------------------------------
| OrderId | Status | CustomerId |
---------------------------------
|    1    |   +    |      2     |
---------------------------------
|    2    |   -    |      1     |
---------------------------------
|    3    |   +    |      2     |
---------------------------------
|    4    |   +    |      1     |
---------------------------------
|    5    |   -    |      3     |
---------------------------------
|    6    |   +    |      4     |
---------------------------------
|    7    |   +    |      3     |
---------------------------------
```

The question is how I can delete the next order after cancelled one for each customer? I basically want to delete order with id = 4, 7.
So the result should be:

```
---------------------------------
| OrderId | Status | CustomerId |
---------------------------------
|    1    |   +    |      2     |
---------------------------------
|    2    |   -    |      1     |
---------------------------------
|    3    |   +    |      2     |
---------------------------------
|    5    |   -    |      3     |
---------------------------------
|    6    |   +    |      4     |
---------------------------------
```

I use SQL Server, but I'm realy curious about writing it using ANSI SQL.

Comment: This can done pretty easily using windowing functions, but older versions of sql-server don't support them. What version of sql-server are you running? If it's older, then a self join `ON orderid = orderid - 1` would probably do the trick too.

Comment: @JNevill, SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last cancelled order for each customer.  Then delete the orders after that:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             min(case when status = '-' then orderid end) over
                 (partition by customerid) as deleted_orderid
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where orderid > deleted_orderid;
```

EDIT:

To delete just the next one, let's use `row_number()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, min(case when orderid > deleted_orderid then orderid end) over
                      (partition by customerid) as orderid_to_delete
      from (select t.*,
                   min(case when status = '-' then orderid end) over
                       (partition by customerid) as deleted_orderid
            from table t
           ) t
     )
delete from todelete
    where orderid = orderid_to_delete;
```

EDIT II:

If you want to delete the next order after *any* delete, the query is a bit simpler:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, lag(status) over (partition by customerid order by orderid) as prev_status
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where prev_status = '-';
```

This is ANSI SQL.  If you are using SQL Server 2008, you need to use a correlated subquery or maybe `cross apply` (I'm not 100% sure that `cross apply` will work in a delete CTE, but it should.)

Comment: I need to delete only one order after canceled. It seems that this code removes all of them, am I right?

Comment: I will revise the answer, but your question clearly says "how I can delete the next orders after cancelled one for each customer".  Note the "next orders . . . for each customer.

Comment: I belive you should remove min() function from nested select, shouldn't you?